# Where can I find the source code of shapely.geometry.multilinestring.interpolate() function?

Tags: python, shapely

When I use `shapely.geometry.multilinestring.interpolate()` function, it creates points at every 50 m **along** the multiline.

I try to create a points at a given interval (lets say the distance between points will be 50 meters). And all these points will be **on** the multiline even in the vertex

I thought I may modify the `shapely.geometry.multilinestring.interpolate()` function, but I could not find it.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely

Comment: Hi Tomazic. Thanks for the answer. I looked every files at its github. I also used find file button to search it but I still I could not find. Can you please just give me the direct web link for the interpolate function?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/blob/master/shapely/geometry/base.py